# How to load an image in active document? (Photoshop Scripting)

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I am new to photoshop scripting.

I want to load an image image (from my hard disk) into the active document as a new layer with positioning. How can this be done? Can somebody please share the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can open Photoshop File Dialog for searching your image and adding that into a layer

```
file = app.openDialog();//opens dialog,choose one image

if(file[0]){ //if you have chosen an image
   app.load(file[0]); //load it into documents
   backFile= app.activeDocument; //prepare your image layer as active document
   backFile.resizeImage(width,height); //resize image into given size i.e 640x480
   backFile.selection.selectAll();
   backFile.selection.copy(); //copy image into clipboard
   backFile.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES); //close image without saving changes
   doc.paste(); //paste selection into your document
   doc.layers[0].name = "BackgroundImage"; //set your layer's name
}
```

There is a good example of making a calendar with photoshop javascript extension (.jsx).

Please check that [here](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/designing-tutorials/create-a-calendar-using-scripting-in-photoshop/)